# unexpected indentifier javascript

Tags: javascript, slider

Here I have a problem,I want to do a slider and I have an unexpected identifier on line `window.clearTimeout(timer)` in both functions `nextSlide()` and `prevSlide()`. Can you help me ?

```
var timer = new Object;

function slider(){
nextSlide();
window.setTimeout(slider, 5000);
}

function nextSlide(){
var $Slides = $(".contenu");
$Slides.animate(
    {left: "-=213px"},
    1000,
    function(){
        $Slides.data("currentSlide",$Slides.data("currentSlide")+1);
        if($Slides.data("currentSlide") > $Slides.data("nbSlides")) {
            $Slides.data("currentSlide",1).css({left:"-213px"});
        }
    }
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = window.setTimeout(slider, 5000);
  );
}

function prevSlide(){
var $Slides = $(".contenu");
$Slides.animate(
    {left:"+=213px"},
    1000,
    function(){
        $Slides.data("currentSlide", $Slides.data("currentSlide")-1);
        if($Slides.data("currentSlide") == 0) {
            $Slides.data("currentSlide",$Slides.data("nbSlides")).css({left:-(213*$Slides.data("currentSlide"))});
        }
    }
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = window.setTimeout(slider, 5000);
);
}
```

Here the loading :

```
$(function(){

slider();


$('#slider').addClass('slider');
var $Slides = $('.contenu');
var _step = $Slides.find(".slide:first").width();

$Slides.data("currentSlide",1).data("nbSlides",$Slides.find('.slide').size());

$Slides.find(".slide:last").clone().prependTo(".contenu");

$Slides.find(".slide:first").next().clone().appendTo('.contenu');

$Slides.find(".slide:first").addClass("clone").end().css({left:-_step});

$Slides.width($Slides.find(".slide").size()*_step);

$('.next').bind("click", nextSlide);
$('.prev').bind("click", prevSlide);
});
```

thx for help. ;)

Comment: At a quick glance, you're doing `setTimeout(slider, 5000)` more than one time at different places. You should consider using `setInterval`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are still in the `.animate()` call, you should move `);` up to above `window.clearTimeout(timer)`.

**This answer assumes you want to set the timeOut directly after you start the animation, if you want to set the timeOut in the callback of the animation you should do what is in David's answer and move it up to above `}`.**

*EDIT:*
Based on your comments I made this function for you:

```
function nextSlide(){
    var $Slides = $(".contenu");
    $Slides.animate(
        {left: "-=213px"},
        1000,
        function(){
            $Slides.data("currentSlide",$Slides.data("currentSlide")+1);
            if($Slides.data("currentSlide") > $Slides.data("nbSlides")) {
                $Slides.data("currentSlide",1).css({left:"-213px"});
            }
            window.clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = window.setTimeout(slider, 5000);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: I put window.clearTimeout(timer) in the callback but now the slider doesn't turn automatically. A solution ? Thanks for answers.

Comment: Are you sure the callback gets called? @JemyDev

Comment: Make sure it is NOT in the if block, but still in the callback. And, you should move `timer = window.setTimeout(slider, 5000);` too. @JemyDev

Comment: `$Slides.animate(
   {left: "-=213px"},
     1000,function(){
   $Slides.data("currentSlide",$Slides.data("currentSlide")+1);
   if($Slides.data("currentSlide") > $Slides.data("nbSlides")) {
    $Slides.data("currentSlide",1).css({left:"-213px"});
   }
  }
 ), function(){
         window.clearTimeout(timer);
 timer = window.setTimeout(slider, 5000);
     };`

I have this, I think the callback is correct isn't it ? @11684

Comment: @JemyDev You already had a callback function, see my edit. That's what I think you meant to do.

Comment: I have another problem, i have two slides which turn but it's not one by one. Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: @JemyDev I don't completely understand. Do you mean it moves two slides every time instead of one? But this is a separate issue, you should create a new thread for that.

Comment: In fact, I had fix this problem, thank you for your answers !

Answer (score 1):

Function call parameters should be separated by commata `,` however in your case, you separate them by semicolons `;` - the line ends with a semicolon instead of a comma. also the next line. This is not a function body with multiple statements, but a function call (to `animate`) so you need to use commas.

On the other hand - these are probably not arguments, so you need to move the closing `);` part above these lines instead, so that they become separate statements instead of function parameters.

Comment: ["semicolons" is much more common than "semicola"](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=semicolons&word2=semicola)

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work :( i tried to put out of the function animate(), but not work.

Comment: @JanDvorak So what? Semicola looks and sounds better. :)

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet:

```
window.clearTimeout(timer);
timer = window.setTimeout(slider, 5000);
```

is placed out of context. You need to place it inside a function or in the global scope to make it work, f.ex:

```
function(){
    $Slides.data("currentSlide", $Slides.data("currentSlide")-1);
    if($Slides.data("currentSlide") == 0) {
        $Slides.data("currentSlide",$Slides.data("nbSlides")).css({left:-(213*$Slides.data("currentSlide"))});
    }
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = window.setTimeout(slider, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using `out of context` correctly? I am not a native English speaker so I am not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: @11684 http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/context_2#context_2__3 `If words are used out of context, only a small separate part of what was originally said or written is reported, which causes their meaning to not be clear or understood` Doesn't seem right.

Comment: Yes, but in this particular scenario it means that the code is in a strange place. @AlvinWong

Comment: I’m not a native English speaker either :) What I mean is that the code snippet will not be executed because you have misplaced it as arguments.